# Where's the connection between index.html and index.js in a Create-React-App application?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm starting to play with the Create React App, but I can't understand how the `index.js` is loaded inside `index.html`. This is the html code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tag above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

But I can't see anywhere the import of the `index.js`. Where is the connection? What am I missing?

Comment: How do you serve your content?

Comment: I haven't changed anything default, I just do this: `create-react-app my-app` and I open the project using webstorm, then I do npm start, but my question is how index.html know that have to load index.js? where is write?

Comment: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html

Webpack-dev-server handles this for you in development.

Comment: @NicklasWinger Where I can find the configuration file to understand the mechanism?

Comment: You can run `npm run eject` to manually control the configs. I recommend doing a more basic setup from scratch to fully understand what's going on :)

Comment: No other answers, except the one from that Dan guy? ;-)

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Under the hood, Create React App uses Webpack with [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin).

Our configuration [specifies](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/21fe19ab0fbae8ca403572beb55b4d11e45a75cf/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js#L68-L70) that Webpack uses `src/index.js` as an [“entry point”](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#entry). So that’s the first module it reads, and it follows from it to other modules to compile them into a single bundle.

When webpack compiles the assets, it produces a single (or several if you use code splitting) bundles. It makes their final paths available to all plugins. We are using one such plugin for injecting scripts into HTML.

We have enabled [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) to generate the HTML file. In our configuration, we [specified](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/21fe19ab0fbae8ca403572beb55b4d11e45a75cf/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js#L233-L235) that it should read `public/index.html` as a template. We have also set `inject` [option](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#configuration) to `true`. With that option, `html-webpack-plugin` adds a `<script>` with the path provided by Webpack right into the final HTML page. This final page is the one you get in `build/index.html` after running `npm run build`, and the one that gets served from `/` when you run `npm start`.

The beauty of Create React App is you don’t actually need to think about it.

Comment: One more question, what IDE do you use for react or js in general? I have fought in the choice between Atom and Webstorm, what do you think?

Comment: I'm using Webstorm and so far I'm really happy with it.

Comment: How do you resolve multiple paths to load different HTML pages?

Comment: Actually @Dan Abramov is a genius :D but i don't agree with him when he said "you don’t actually need to think about it" because everybody should understand things from the bottom up.

Comment: Hopefully this is documented somewhere else besides here? In CRA documentation?  We don't need to know the implementation but we do need to know things start with index.js and how it mangles public/index.html Thanks to all!

Comment: @Dan Abramov Where does the page that gets served from `/` from `npm start` get stored? I want to map to it with Homestead, but can't seem to find where it puts those files.

Comment: Well everything has it's black and white, some said it's done, some said it's not. Depends on your field of research, and your interests as well. I prefer digging more, that's why I am here ;)

Comment: Is there an option in CRA to generate a new project like this, with index.html as entry point? then we really wouldn't need to worry about it ...