# How is the JavaScript file attached to the HTML in React?

Tags: reactjs

I recently stumbled over this question in an interview. I can't seem to find too much about it online.

Q: How is the index.js file attached to the HTML file in React?

I have to be honest, I'm not clear on this. Here is the head of the index.html file of a standard create-react-app. I don't see any links for JS or CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">

    <title>My App</title>
  </head>
```

I just want to make sure I understand how everything is working under the hood. Apologies for the semi-basic question.

Comment: why are you just looking at the head and not the body?

Comment: anyways, it's a webpack plugin that does it. it's not specific to react, but specific to the way create-react-app uses webpack

Comment: We attach it as a bundle js file in the <body> tag in my project
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/js/client.js"></script>
</body>

Comment: I know that <div id="root"></div> is where the React app gets injected. But in standard HTML you need to actually link the files. I don't see the link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create React App index.html and index.js connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438171/create-react-app-index-html-and-index-js-connection)

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42440000/9264167

This might help you to know better about what is happening behind the scene.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is only the template used by webpack. Take a look at your webpack.config.js and you will find the used plugin, which is responsible for creating css and javascript bundles.