# How to use webpack with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've created a [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) project following the [documentation provided by create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started)

1) I create my project and cd into it

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
```

2) I've followed the [getting started documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) and installed [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack), webpack-cli, and webpack-dev-server.

```
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-dev-server webpack-cli
```

3) Considering that babel is needed Ive also followed these steps from [this instruction](https://www.robinwieruch.de/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup/)

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env
npm install --save-dev babel-loader
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react
```

4) I've also created the following **webpack.config.js** file following [this instruction](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/#using-a-configuration)

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
            "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"]        }
          }
        }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

See below for my package.json below

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build:dev": "webpack"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.28.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
}
```

When I run the following command

```
npm run start:dev
```

I get the following error

```
 webpack-dev-server

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
✖ ｢wdm｣: Hash: ebe0431a84f29f0e98e9
Version: webpack 4.28.3
Time: 5058ms
Built at: 01/05/2019 1:49:37 PM
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
 [0] ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes {0} [built]
 [4] ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 1.33 KiB {0} [built]
 [5] ./src/logo.svg 2.65 KiB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
 [6] ./src/serviceWorker.js 4.6 KiB {0} [built]
 [7] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
 [8] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 7.78 KiB {0} [built]
 [9] ./node_modules/url/url.js 22.8 KiB {0} [built]
[16] ./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
[18] ./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 7.68 KiB {0} [built]
[19] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {0} [built]
[21] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.58 KiB {0} [built]
[26] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {0} [built]
[28] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75 bytes {0} [built]
[34] ./src/index.css 168 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[37] ./src/index.js + 1 modules 3.58 KiB {0} [built]
     | ./src/index.js 472 bytes [built]
     | ./src/App.js 3.09 KiB [built]
    + 23 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/App.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> .App {
|   text-align: center;
| }
 @ ./src/App.js 21:0-19
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/logo.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 841.9 595.3">
|     <g fill="#61DAFB">
|         <path d="M666.3 296.5c0-32.5-40.7-63.3-103.1-82.4 14.4-63.6 8-114.2-20.2-130.4-6.5-3.8-14.1-5.6-22.4-5.6v22.3c4.6 0 8.3.9 11.4 2.6 13.6 7.8 19.5 37.5 14.9 75.7-1.1 9.4-2.9 19.3-5.1 29.4-19.6-4.8-41-8.5-63.5-10.9-13.5-18.5-27.5-35.3-41.6-50 32.6-30.3 63.2-46.9 84-46.9V78c-27.5 0-63.5 19.6-99.9 53.6-36.4-33.8-72.4-53.2-99.9-53.2v22.3c20.7 0 51.4 16.5 84 46.6-14 14.7-28 31.4-41.3 49.9-22.6 2.4-44 6.1-63.6 11-2.3-10-4-19.7-5.2-29-4.7-38.2 1.1-67.9 14.6-75.8 3-1.8 6.9-2.6 11.5-2.6V78.5c-8.4 0-16 1.8-22.6 5.6-28.1 16.2-34.4 66.7-19.9 130.1-62.2 19.2-102.7 49.9-102.7 82.3 0 32.5 40.7 63.3 103.1 82.4-14.4 63.6-8 114.2 20.2 130.4 6.5 3.8 14.1 5.6 22.5 5.6 27.5 0 63.5-19.6 99.9-53.6 36.4 33.8 72.4 53.2 99.9 53.2 8.4 0 16-1.8 22.6-5.6 28.1-16.2 34.4-66.7 19.9-130.1 62-19.1 102.5-49.9 102.5-82.3zm-130.2-66.7c-3.7 12.9-8.3 26.2-13.5 39.5-4.1-8-8.4-16-13.1-24-4.6-8-9.5-15.8-14.4-23.4 14.2 2.1 27.9 4.7 41 7.9zm-45.8 106.5c-7.8 13.5-15.8 26.3-24.1 38.2-14.9 1.3-30 2-45.2 2-15.1 0-30.2-.7-45-1.9-8.3-11.9-16.4-24.6-24.2-38-7.6-13.1-14.5-26.4-20.8-39.8 6.2-13.4 13.2-26.8 20.7-39.9 7.8-13.5 15.8-26.3 24.1-38.2 14.9-1.3 30-2 45.2-2 15.1 0 30.2.7 45 1.9 8.3 11.9 16.4 24.6 24.2 38 7.6 13.1 14.5 26.4 20.8 39.8-6.3 13.4-13.2 26.8-20.7 39.9zm32.3-13c5.4 13.4 10 26.8 13.8 39.8-13.1 3.2-26.9 5.9-41.2 8 4.9-7.7 9.8-15.6 14.4-23.7 4.6-8 8.9-16.1 13-24.1zM421.2 430c-9.3-9.6-18.6-20.3-27.8-32 9 .4 18.2.7 27.5.7 9.4 0 18.7-.2 27.8-.7-9 11.7-18.3 22.4-27.5 32zm-74.4-58.9c-14.2-2.1-27.9-4.7-41-7.9 3.7-12.9 8.3-26.2 13.5-39.5 4.1 8 8.4 16 13.1 24 4.7 8 9.5 15.8 14.4 23.4zM420.7 163c9.3 9.6 18.6 20.3 27.8 32-9-.4-18.2-.7-27.5-.7-9.4 0-18.7.2-27.8.7 9-11.7 18.3-22.4 27.5-32zm-74 58.9c-4.9 7.7-9.8 15.6-14.4 23.7-4.6 8-8.9 16-13 24-5.4-13.4-10-26.8-13.8-39.8 13.1-3.1 26.9-5.8 41.2-7.9zm-90.5 125.2c-35.4-15.1-58.3-34.9-58.3-50.6 0-15.7 22.9-35.6 58.3-50.6 8.6-3.7 18-7 27.7-10.1 5.7 19.6 13.2 40 22.5 60.9-9.2 20.8-16.6 41.1-22.2 60.6-9.9-3.1-19.3-6.5-28-10.2zM310 490c-13.6-7.8-19.5-37.5-14.9-75.7 1.1-9.4 2.9-19.3 5.1-29.4 19.6 4.8 41 8.5 63.5 10.9 13.5 18.5 27.5 35.3 41.6 50-32.6 30.3-63.2 46.9-84 46.9-4.5-.1-8.3-1-11.3-2.7zm237.2-76.2c4.7 38.2-1.1 67.9-14.6 75.8-3 1.8-6.9 2.6-11.5 2.6-20.7 0-51.4-16.5-84-46.6 14-14.7 28-31.4 41.3-49.9 22.6-2.4 44-6.1 63.6-11 2.3 10.1 4.1 19.8 5.2 29.1zm38.5-66.7c-8.6 3.7-18 7-27.7 10.1-5.7-19.6-13.2-40-22.5-60.9 9.2-20.8 16.6-41.1 22.2-60.6 9.9 3.1 19.3 6.5 28.1 10.2 35.4 15.1 58.3 34.9 58.3 50.6-.1 15.7-23 35.6-58.4 50.6zM320.8 78.4z"/>
 @ ./src/App.js 20:0-30 42:13-17
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/index.css 1:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> body {
|   margin: 0;
|   padding: 0;
 @ ./src/index.js 3:0-21
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

I also ran the following command

```
npm run build:dev
```

This generated this error:

```
> my-app@0.1.0 build:dev /Users/chriscruz/Desktop/my-app
> webpack

Hash: eff8d3ad52e3c88d156c
Version: webpack 4.28.3
Time: 2647ms
Built at: 01/05/2019 1:54:01 PM
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
 [3] ./src/logo.svg 2.65 KiB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
 [4] ./src/serviceWorker.js 4.6 KiB {0} [built]
 [9] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
[10] ./src/index.css 168 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[11] ./src/App.css 165 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[13] ./src/index.js + 1 modules 3.58 KiB {0} [built]
     | ./src/index.js 472 bytes [built]
     | ./src/App.js 3.09 KiB [built]
    + 8 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/App.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> .App {
|   text-align: center;
| }
 @ ./src/App.js 21:0-19
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/logo.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 841.9 595.3">
|     <g fill="#61DAFB">
|         <path d="M666.3 296.5c0-32.5-40.7-63.3-103.1-82.4 14.4-63.6 8-114.2-20.2-130.4-6.5-3.8-14.1-5.6-22.4-5.6v22.3c4.6 0 8.3.9 11.4 2.6 13.6 7.8 19.5 37.5 14.9 75.7-1.1 9.4-2.9 19.3-5.1 29.4-19.6-4.8-41-8.5-63.5-10.9-13.5-18.5-27.5-35.3-41.6-50 32.6-30.3 63.2-46.9 84-46.9V78c-27.5 0-63.5 19.6-99.9 53.6-36.4-33.8-72.4-53.2-99.9-53.2v22.3c20.7 0 51.4 16.5 84 46.6-14 14.7-28 31.4-41.3 49.9-22.6 2.4-44 6.1-63.6 11-2.3-10-4-19.7-5.2-29-4.7-38.2 1.1-67.9 14.6-75.8 3-1.8 6.9-2.6 11.5-2.6V78.5c-8.4 0-16 1.8-22.6 5.6-28.1 16.2-34.4 66.7-19.9 130.1-62.2 19.2-102.7 49.9-102.7 82.3 0 32.5 40.7 63.3 103.1 82.4-14.4 63.6-8 114.2 20.2 130.4 6.5 3.8 14.1 5.6 22.5 5.6 27.5 0 63.5-19.6 99.9-53.6 36.4 33.8 72.4 53.2 99.9 53.2 8.4 0 16-1.8 22.6-5.6 28.1-16.2 34.4-66.7 19.9-130.1 62-19.1 102.5-49.9 102.5-82.3zm-130.2-66.7c-3.7 12.9-8.3 26.2-13.5 39.5-4.1-8-8.4-16-13.1-24-4.6-8-9.5-15.8-14.4-23.4 14.2 2.1 27.9 4.7 41 7.9zm-45.8 106.5c-7.8 13.5-15.8 26.3-24.1 38.2-14.9 1.3-30 2-45.2 2-15.1 0-30.2-.7-45-1.9-8.3-11.9-16.4-24.6-24.2-38-7.6-13.1-14.5-26.4-20.8-39.8 6.2-13.4 13.2-26.8 20.7-39.9 7.8-13.5 15.8-26.3 24.1-38.2 14.9-1.3 30-2 45.2-2 15.1 0 30.2.7 45 1.9 8.3 11.9 16.4 24.6 24.2 38 7.6 13.1 14.5 26.4 20.8 39.8-6.3 13.4-13.2 26.8-20.7 39.9zm32.3-13c5.4 13.4 10 26.8 13.8 39.8-13.1 3.2-26.9 5.9-41.2 8 4.9-7.7 9.8-15.6 14.4-23.7 4.6-8 8.9-16.1 13-24.1zM421.2 430c-9.3-9.6-18.6-20.3-27.8-32 9 .4 18.2.7 27.5.7 9.4 0 18.7-.2 27.8-.7-9 11.7-18.3 22.4-27.5 32zm-74.4-58.9c-14.2-2.1-27.9-4.7-41-7.9 3.7-12.9 8.3-26.2 13.5-39.5 4.1 8 8.4 16 13.1 24 4.7 8 9.5 15.8 14.4 23.4zM420.7 163c9.3 9.6 18.6 20.3 27.8 32-9-.4-18.2-.7-27.5-.7-9.4 0-18.7.2-27.8.7 9-11.7 18.3-22.4 27.5-32zm-74 58.9c-4.9 7.7-9.8 15.6-14.4 23.7-4.6 8-8.9 16-13 24-5.4-13.4-10-26.8-13.8-39.8 13.1-3.1 26.9-5.8 41.2-7.9zm-90.5 125.2c-35.4-15.1-58.3-34.9-58.3-50.6 0-15.7 22.9-35.6 58.3-50.6 8.6-3.7 18-7 27.7-10.1 5.7 19.6 13.2 40 22.5 60.9-9.2 20.8-16.6 41.1-22.2 60.6-9.9-3.1-19.3-6.5-28-10.2zM310 490c-13.6-7.8-19.5-37.5-14.9-75.7 1.1-9.4 2.9-19.3 5.1-29.4 19.6 4.8 41 8.5 63.5 10.9 13.5 18.5 27.5 35.3 41.6 50-32.6 30.3-63.2 46.9-84 46.9-4.5-.1-8.3-1-11.3-2.7zm237.2-76.2c4.7 38.2-1.1 67.9-14.6 75.8-3 1.8-6.9 2.6-11.5 2.6-20.7 0-51.4-16.5-84-46.6 14-14.7 28-31.4 41.3-49.9 22.6-2.4 44-6.1 63.6-11 2.3 10.1 4.1 19.8 5.2 29.1zm38.5-66.7c-8.6 3.7-18 7-27.7 10.1-5.7-19.6-13.2-40-22.5-60.9 9.2-20.8 16.6-41.1 22.2-60.6 9.9 3.1 19.3 6.5 28.1 10.2 35.4 15.1 58.3 34.9 58.3 50.6-.1 15.7-23 35.6-58.4 50.6zM320.8 78.4z"/>
 @ ./src/App.js 20:0-30 42:13-17
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/index.css 1:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> body {
|   margin: 0;
|   padding: 0;
 @ ./src/index.js 3:0-21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 build:dev: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 build:dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/chriscruz/.npm/_logs/2019-01-05T18_54_01_643Z-debug.log
```

Comment: If you're using create-react-app you can simply use eject... https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject

Comment: What is your create-react-app version? You can find out by `npx create-react-app -V`

Answer (score 10):

When you use the `create-react-app` you have already installed and pre-configured 
 webpack, you can build your project using `npm run build` command. If you want to use a non-standard webpack configuration, you can run `npm run eject` command, after which the configuration files will be created in your project and you can change them.

Answer (score 0):

A React app created using [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/) generally do not use a `webpack.config.js`. That is "by design" to simplify and streamline the app creation process. As the docs [note](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#get-started-immediately):

> You don’t need to install or configure tools like webpack or Babel.
> They are preconfigured and hidden so that you can focus on the code.

And, per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42440000/3368818) answer, by a create-react-app co-creator

> Under the hood, Create React App uses Webpack with
> html-webpack-plugin.

To modify an app initially created using `create-react-app` in order to add more customization to the build process, such as adding webpack, there are a couple (at least) different options:

- The seemingly most common approach is to "eject" your React app so that you can add more customization to its build and configuration options. This approach begins with running `npm run eject`, as described [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject).
- You can [fork](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/alternatives-to-ejecting/) react-scripts as an alternative to the "eject" from create-react-app approach.
- You could use [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired), which describes itself as a way to "Tweak the create-react-app webpack config(s) without using 'eject' and without creating a fork of the react-scripts".