# Electron - React component is not rendered

Tags: reactjs, electron

i have been trying for days to familiarize myself with the supposedly simple electron framework with react library. however, i have to give up now and offer you to help me.

here is my simple project:

[image]

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" />

    <title>My page</title>

  </head>
  <body>

    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>

    <!-- -->
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

*main.js*

```
const electron  = require('electron');
const path      = require('path');
const url       = require('url');

const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

let mainWindow;

// Listen for app to be ready
app.on('ready', function(){

    // Create new window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

    // Load html in window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));

    // Quit app when closed
    mainWindow.on('closed', function(){
        app.quit();
    });
});
```

*src/index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Dashboard from './pages/dashboard';

ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

*src/pages/dashboard.js*

```
import React from 'react';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                Test Message
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "create-react-app",
  "version": "3.2.2",
  "private": true,
  "main": "public/main.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "4.0.6",
    "foreman": "3.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "3.9.2",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I can build the application and start it, but the HTML page (Dashboard) is not displayed.

I would be happy about any help.

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: No errors. Just blank electron window.

Comment: I dont know how do you bundle your js files, but your `index.html` files doesnt have script tag with the corresponding `bundle.js` file, that's why it shows empty window :)

Comment: It should be happen while `build` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438171/create-react-app-index-html-and-index-js-connection

Comment: Have you started your React server? You may need to have one script to start React, and then another to launch Electron once the React app has been built and launched.