# Adding js script to the React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i add a simple, classic *js* script to the react project?
I've tried to add it just by adding

```
<script src="../src/alert.js"></script>
```

in the *head* of the *index.html* but it seems not to work!

Comment: Did you try to add it inside the `index.js` -> `import './alert.js';`

Comment: Thx, that helped, but why cant i add it from the main `index.html` file?

Answer (score 1):

[Here the Dan Abramov's answer say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438171/wheres-the-connection-between-index-html-and-index-js-in-a-create-react-app-app)

> Under the hood, Create React App uses Webpack with
> html-webpack-plugin.

The `index.html` is use as a template and the `index.js` is your **entry point** of you app

```
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
```

So if you want to load additional script you have to import them inside the `index.js`.

Comment: Ok, thx. I understand. Don't be angry but I'll ask - again why doesn't it work when i'm adding the script using classic js `<script>` tag?

Comment: Can You be so nice and answer my last question?