# I have not added script to HTML file but the react app still works, how?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am currently learning react and I have ran into a problem

This is my code for index.html in the public folder :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>React App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My index.js in src file :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<h1 contentEditable= "true">Hello World</h1>,document.getElementById("root"))
```

Since I haven't added my script to my HTML file how is it still working? How does a React app start, I mean whats the first thing does it do on npm start?

Comment: What does it say next to "start" in package.json/scripts? I assume `"react-scrips start"`? That's why. The command pre-processes the index.html file; for instance it replaces `%PUBLIC_URL%` with the actual URL. It also adds the script tag. You can also check the source in your browser; just press Ctrl+U. You will see the script tag.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app):

Possible duplication of:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42440000/7337695

Comment: If it's a duplicate, please don't post an answer. Just flag the question as such.