# How does a React application start without explicit references to its JS implementation files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React.  In the tic-tac-toe game ( https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html ) the index.html file had some event handlers and a div pointing at id=root.  But nothing about an index.js file, which has a ReactDOM.render.

What tells the browser to run the index.js code if there is no  tag loading it?

*This* link ( [Where's the connection between index.html and index.js in a Create-React-App application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438171/wheres-the-connection-between-index-html-and-index-js-in-a-create-react-app-app) ) says:

> Our configuration specifies that Webpack uses src/index.js as an “entry point”. So that’s the first module it reads, and it follows from it to other modules to compile them into a single bundle.

> When webpack compiles the assets, it produces a single (or several if you use code splitting) bundles. It makes their final paths available to all plugins. We are using one such plugin for injecting scripts into HTML.

But if this is the answer, then why should a browser know about webpack, especially as this isn't mentioned in the minimal index.html file?

Comment: Browser doesn't know anything about webpack which prepares everything to get served ***to*** the browser. For example you could take the whole build folder and upload to a remote server  where webpack doesn't exist and that server will deliver the production version of what you have been developing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running npm run build.
the index.html file discussed in the answer above is in the build directory produced by webpack after running that command.

> Under the hood, Create React App uses Webpack with html-webpack-plugin.

this plugin will be producing the index.html file by using the index.html in the `public` directory as a template

> Our configuration specifies that Webpack uses src/index.js as an “entry point”. So that’s the first module it reads, and it follows from it to other modules to compile them into a single bundle.

when running npm run build webpack starts with index.js and every time you import it includes that module in one script that would be injected into the index.html generated above as explained below in the answer you shared

> We have enabled html-webpack-plugin to generate the HTML file. In our configuration, we specified that it should read public/index.html as a template. We have also set inject option to true. With that option, html-webpack-plugin adds a  with the path provided by Webpack right into the final HTML page. This final page is the one you get in build/index.html after running npm run build, and the one that gets served from / when you run npm start.

This is my understanding I hope this helps.

Comment: No matter what you provide in Webpack, it must still be referenced by the initial HTML page (in this case, index.html).  Yet in the example, see the tic-tac-toe link from the reactjs.org site there are no *.js references.  Nor in the git version https://github.com/harman052/react-tutorial-solutions/blob/master/public/index.html

Comment: I see the confusion the index.html you shared is being used only as a template that is what you see before the script containing your JS code is running.
This template is used by webpack to output the "real" index.html which exist in the build directory and contains a script tag with either a src or directly injects JS within the script tag when you run `npm run build`

Comment: OK, the in-browser runner at codepen.io is effectively lying to me.  There is *something* that modifies index.html so that it causes ReactDOM.render to run.  For these demos, I'll see if I can convince my browser to show me the modified version.  Unless you'd like to add something, I'll soon mark this Q as being solved...

Answer (score 2):

The create-react-app build script tells webpack to create the bundle(s), starting with src/index.js as the entry point. Also part of this build script is to create a modified version of the index.html file which points to the newly-created bundle file(s). You can find the modified index.html file in your `/build` directory, and it will have gained something like the following:

```
<script src="/static/js/main.379f1d19.chunk.js"></script>
```

That script tag is how the browser knows what to load.